# SonarQube: ERROR - Unable to retreive coverage onfo for file , because: {}

Tags: angular, sonarqube

I have angular2 application(typescript). I am trying to run sonarqube analysis against the typescript files, but hitting with below error:

```
>14:46:12.876 ERROR - Unable to retreive coverage onfo for file , because: {}
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at com.pablissimo.sonar.LCOVParser.parse(LCOVParser.java:73) [sonar-typescript-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at com.pablissimo.sonar.LCOVParser.parseFile(LCOVParser.java:59) [sonar-typescript-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at com.pablissimo.sonar.TsCoverageSensor.saveMeasureFromLCOVFile(TsCoverageSensor.java:86) [sonar-typescript-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at com.pablissimo.sonar.TsCoverageSensor.analyse(TsCoverageSensor.java:59) [sonar-typescript-plugin-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:79) [sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48) [sonar-runner-batch2069977240354308118.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45]
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: To get an answer I think would be better to create an issue directly in the community SonarTsPlugin that you seem to use: https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin/issues.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.